# Philosophy of understanding

Tags: knowledge

Is there any good text of philosophy that describes or investigates how understanding or knowledge happens? Something on the lines of heuristics. I have read a book called How to Solve it by G. Polya its about heuristics of problem-solving. But that's too limited to mathematics. So I was wondering if any philosopher has done work on this topic?

Comment: You might find this answer interesting: 'According to the major theories of concepts, where do meanings come from?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77261/according-to-the-major-theories-of-concepts-where-do-meanings-come-from/77284#77284

Comment: Heuristics are field specific, so if you want some applicable methodology like Polya's it will necessarily be limited to its field. Philosophy of understanding texts, for example, is called [hermeneutics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hermeneutics/), and a number of approaches and strategies have been developed for the task.

Comment: Thanks. What about `learning` ? Is there some work in this field too?