# Can the product of creativity always be classified as analogy?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, aesthetics, analogy, creativity, philosophy-of-design

[*Without concepts there can be no thought, and without
analogies there can be no concepts.*
—Hofstadter and Sander](https://books.google.com/books?id=92e30rzcoCkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=analogy%20as%20the%20fire%20sanders%20hoffstadter%27&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwuMCYo7T-AhVhjIkEHbkGBFoQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Part of the creative process of a sculpter is to visualize a shape within a stone and then create an analogue of that shape from the stone. Or simply look at a stone and visualize all the analogues that can be created from the stone. Is this a form of analogy?
Is creativity possible without analogy?
Is it correct to claim that the product of true creativity has no analogy?

Comment: What is _creativity_? Is creativity based on analogy more like a weak form of _copying_ than really _creating_? To really create something new, shouldn't the creation be without prior images? In what ways?

Comment: @Frank I soooo did not want to go down that avenue.  I'm asking about the product of creativity. Is that product always an analogy to another previous product?

Comment: @Frank So the product of true creativity has no analogy?  I like that.

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting: if there is an analogy to something already existing, is it really "_creative_"? To me, it seems reasonable to argue that something really _creative_ has to be never seen before in any way, shape or form... Of course, now we can debate to what extent that is true or not.

Comment: If it's the result of an analogy, it seems the creativity that went in is only in changing the product? Maybe that's also a type of creativity. So now, we could categorize types of creativity: pure creativity, incremental creativity, creativity through modifications, creativity ex nihilo, ...

Comment: @Frank I'm trying to black-box creativity. Rather than trying to determine what creativity is, I'm interested in how creativity behaves. What are the products of creativity and how to evaluate them. Innovation is a form of creativity that always has analogy.

Comment: But if the terms are not properly defined, the discussion could go in circles. I could argue that creativity is always by analogy and that a sculptor never creates something really new, but I could also argue that "creativity" is only in the difference between 2 statues, and thus never by analogy, since analogy can't produce anything new.

Comment: @Frank Everthing is new and magical to an infant. Is analogy part of the process that begins filling the infants brain?

Comment: Is that a question separate from "creativity" though? I am not a specialist, but it seems reasonable to imagine that analogy plays a big role in infant learning.

Comment: @Frank I think the two are intertwined (at least partially)

Comment: I see where this is going - I think it's going to be a question of how much "creativity" there is when you have been immersed in a world of things already. But there has to be something completely new on top of analogies, because analogy only would be like copying without ever adding anything new?

Comment: @Frank Yes. I'm just having trouble articulating it. Is analogy fundamental to natural or artificial intelligence ? It's a both a non-numerical classification system and a process engine.

Comment: If an ML model provides an answer that is the average in some sense of what it has seen in its training, you could ask whether an average is "creative" or not. The average of 0 and 10 is 5 which is a "new" number, but also which is not so "new" since it's calculated from the pre-existing 0 and 10, maybe. In ML, this would relate to the problem of "generalization". We expect models to generalize to "new" data that conforms to the same distribution as in training. Is it then really "new"?

Comment: Analogy is an easier read that GEB, but still unnecessarily prolix!

Comment: I can think of no analogy for [Schoenberg's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Schoenberg) atonal chromaticism.

Answer (score 4):

Creativity is possible without analogy.

[Analogy and analogical reasoning (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-analogy/) require a certain element that is arguably missing in some acts of creativity:

> An analogy is a comparison between two objects, or systems of objects, that highlights respects in which they are thought to be similar. Analogical reasoning is any type of thinking that relies upon an analogy. An analogical argument is an explicit representation of a form of analogical reasoning that cites accepted similarities between two systems to support the conclusion that some further similarity exists.

Implicit in this definition, is the idea that there are objects among whom structures exist and have similarity. Thus, an engineer may create a glider by analogy with a bird. Here, the design is an act of creation that relies on analogy. Wings to wings, beak to nosecone, movement style to movement style, and so on. Yet, there are some acts of [creativity (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/creativity/)  that neither register nor require an analogy or analogical thinking. Let's draw from the fine arts. From the SEP:

> Now suppose you are looking at a creative product, like a painting or sculpture. The philosophy of art may ask, “What makes this a work of art?” and aesthetics may ask, “What makes this beautiful?”. By contrast, the philosophy of creativity asks, “What makes this creative? Is it just that it’s new, or must it meet further conditions?”

Some proposed conditions of creativity listed in the article are:

> 2.2.1 Surprise
> 2.2.2 Originality
> 2.2.3 Spontaneity
> 2.2.4 Agency

Thus, one may create a product such a plane by looking at a bird and meet these criteria. Certainly, many people were astonished when seeing the Wright Brothers' plane for the first time. As it was the first plane to function, certainly it was the original plane in some sense of the word. The individual steps to design and engineer the plane was probably composed of one or more Eureka! moments. And of course, humans were involved in the design and implementation at Kittyhawk, NC. Therefore, if analogies were used to create the first functional plane, it should come as no surprise that all told, the first plane was an act of creativity.

But what should we make of [Jackson Pollock's art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Pollock)? Should we conclude the his works were done by some sort of analogical reasoning? I would say no. How can we argue that [*The She Wolf* (1943) (MOMA)](https://www.moma.org/collection/works/78719) is derived from analogy? Perhaps something like "Blind Variation" is the explanation:

> Psychologist Donald T. Campbell (1960, 1965) proposed that creative thought proceeds through “blind variation and selective retention (BVSR)”. The “variations” he refers to are the various ideas that might occur to a creator, and the process of generating them is “blind” to the extent that it is not guided or directed by prior knowledge of how valuable or useful they will be: “Real gains must have been the products of explorations going beyond the limits of foresight or prescience, and in this sense blind” (Campbell 1960: 92, emphasis added).

So unlike the creative act of formulating a creative legal argument, or a novel algorithm, or creating a new technology *de novo*, there are some creative acts that seem to rely heavily on spontaneity without teleological preoccupation. In this sense, they are much more expressive, and any analysis that occurs after the fact, may not have actually played a role in the creative act itself. Thus, we can remind ourselves that not all actions are deliberately driven to achieve or attain, but are often done with non-cognitive emotions, like [the dance of a strange girl at a school function (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsXdUtlDVhk).

Comment: Wednesday's dance put me in mind of Black Swan, and how going beyond the perfection of form often involves a little madness. Synaesthesia may seem like our neurology doing analogies between the senses. But apophenia like the disturbing room of animated paintings & their eyes, can arrive as intrusion rather than an invited analogy. When artists voluntarily push into madness to go beyond the perfection of craft, it's more like an invocation than a making..

Comment: @JD Can analogy be used to classify creativity? Original: No analogy. Innovation: Analogy with a qualitative or quantitative degree: Copy: Perfect analogy

Comment: @StevanV.Saban I see you are liking my idea of cataloguing "creativities" depending on how much copying or pure novelty there is :-)

Comment: @CriglCragl Very articulate, good sir. I've heard artists claim they weren't responsible for the creativity they usher into the world. Philosophy and logic are largely the process of appropriating intuition and binding it to the domain of language. One can argue that even the strength of the Viking beserker lies in the creative act of violence.

Comment: @Frank And would you care to speculate on the metrics involved in creating a well-ordering of creativity? I hear you're a huge fan of measurement. ; )

Comment: @StevanV.Saban I would say that if analogy is part of the metric, than it's the systematic framework for decomposing an act of creativity into subacts of creativity. If a novel work has some resemblances, those resemblances each can be analyzed systematically by moving through the partial order of correspondences.

Comment: @JD The interesting part of an analogy is that it has both comparison and contrast operations. Current binary logic only has comparison operators and contrast seems to be an inverse of comparison. I don't believe that a contrast operation is the inverse of a comparison but I have nothing to back that up with.

Comment: @Frank I definitely like your idea. Describing creativity is a necessary part of describing general intelligence

Comment: "The She Wolf" would not have been possible without an analogy between the painting and the appearance of a wolf. Pollock's drip painting would not have been possible without an analogy between painting and dance. Every time you create something, you are applying cognitive functions that you developed from different subjects.

Comment: @causative I believe in the conceptual metaphor, so what you say isn't objectionable. Let me reflect in my hesitation to endorse your view as explicated.

Comment: @JD Thanks. The not equal comparison is a contrast operator. So a compare and contrast algorithm would input two objects and produce counts of equalities and counts of non-equalities.

Comment: @JD I believe that's a weakness with the SEP definition of analogy. It should include both comparison and contrast

Comment: @JD I'm just raising that it would be good philosophical work to look at definition and cataloguing first. Otherwise, the discussion can go in circles.

Comment: This begs the question that She Wolf is creative, or, indeed, art.

Comment: @Frank First you reject impredicativity is useful circularity. Then, you refuse to admit that a recursive function call visits the executable segment circularly. Now you claim that conversations shouldn't go in circles. I guess we can rule out your belief in reincarnation as circular existence, eh? ; )

Comment: @DanielB lol True dat.

Comment: Couldn't you argue that analogy is involved in the "selective retention" part of BVSR? There must be some quality involved when deciding what to retain, and that requires analogy with the desired resulit.

Comment: In physics, the thought experiment "Gedankenexperiment" was a powerful tool for Einstein. Isn't the thought experiment a form of applied analogy to help solidify concepts that were otherwise difficult to visualize? I can't help thinking that analogy is a core function for intelligence and creativity. So I find it surprising that AI has not mastered it. In fact, AI seems unable to create analogies.

Comment: You listed 4 conditions for creativity in your answer. If you had to apply value to these conditions, how would you begin?

Comment: @StevanV.Saban No idea. I'm still investigating the philosophy of language. This topic is years down the road. ; )

Comment: @JD But planes don't flap their wings.....

Comment: @quanity Correction. Functional planes don't flap their wings. There were quite a few attempts before Kittyhawk to create flight by mechanical flapping. ; )

Answer (score 2):

Creativity is not possible without analogy. Hardly any thought is possible without analogy.

From a cognitive standpoint, what is analogy? Analogy is when you apply cognitive functions that are associated with one kind of object to a different kind of object. For example, you have cognitive functions that help you imagine the rolling sea. When you consider the analogical phrase, a "sea of wheat," you are applying the cognitive functions that help you imagine the ocean, to help you imagine the wheat swaying in the wind like waves.

Speaking very broadly this underlies all of cognition. All of cognition is about applying the right cognitive functions for the current situation. The only way we have to know which are the right cognitive functions for the current situation is by analogy to similar situations.

To be creative means to produce a new kind of object. To do this we have to apply cognitive functions to decide the shape and properties of the new object. Where did we develop these cognitive functions? We developed them from learning how to think about other objects. To be creative, therefore, means to apply cognitive functions developed for other objects, to the new object. That's analogy.

Comment: From a design perspective, how is analogy incorporated into overall intelligence design? Is it an add-on or a base to build on?  From an AI perspective,  I can see both analogy processors and analogy-based memory addressing. It seems analogy is a base to build on.

Comment: Maybe there is an analogical phase when a sculptor goes from one sculpture to another, but maybe there is also a purely creative phase, which produces a sculpture different from the prior one, a sculpture that has something new and never seen before.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban Not true. Contrast is where things are not equal.

Comment: Okay. Purvis's *Brains as Engines of Associations* and computationalism for intuition I have no problem with, so I have no problem with calling faculties of intuition association. And analogy is a type of association. And most of analogical reasoning is intuitive. But not all intuitive faculties are analogical. Dancing a new dance is not analogical nor is it reasoning. After using intuition to create a new dance, one can even apply analysis. But, the act of creating a new dance analogizes what? Spontaneous physical movements and the art they might create aren't rooted in what analogy means...

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=analogy The origin is to pick out with words, and that's what analogy means. From WP: "Analogy (from Greek analogia, "proportion", from ana- "upon, according to" [also "against", "anew"] + logos "ratio" [also "word, speech, reckoning"][1][2]) is a cognitive process of transferring information or meaning from a particular subject (the analog, or source) to another (the target), or a linguistic expression corresponding to such a process."

Comment: At it's core, it's a consciously experienced, symbol-centric way of processing information and meaning. There are many acts of creativity that do not follow this. I'm not going to downvote, bc the answer doesn't feel wrong, but to claim all cognition "transfers information or meaning to another or is some expression of language which does such" just doesn't describe acts of creativity that have nothing to do with grammar.

Answer (score 2):

The subtitle of their book is 'Analogy as the Fuel and Fire of Thinking' - now, are fuel and fire the whole constituents of doing mechanical work? Even extending to the most generous interpretation, we can get the general physics from heat-engines, but there is more to what we can do, and how we can do it.

We can learn physical tasks from mimicking others, because when we watch someone do a task the motor signals for us to do it respond. Is that an analogy? Maybe in a sense. But it isn't conceptual, it doesn't involve abstract thought - in fact that often gets in the way of this mode of learning.

A range of corvids who have never before seen the task, have been shown capable of improvising the behaviour Aesop described in [The Crow And The Pitcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crow_and_the_Pitcher#The_fable_in_science). Are they using analogy? Language? Abstraction? If so, it likely isn't with the normal meaning we have for those words, and not problem solving of the kind that involved tuition by a parent; it seems to linked to evolutionary drivers of brain structures. Hard to be sure though.

Octopuses are a clearer example. For most species, after they disperse from their eggs they only encounter other octopuses when breeding. But they have been shown to have behaviours that strongly suggest they understand things about the minds of their predators and prey, to develop complex learned hunting strategies, solve problems like using a key in a door or unscrewing a jar, and behaviours that seem to be creative play. Are they making analogies? It just becomes a meaningless term at this point if so, just meaning pattern recognition, and subsuming intersubjective capacities like mirror-neurons and theory-of-mind, which I don't think really fit.

I read an interesting study that I haven't been able to locate, that showed a 'noisy' mind is good for embellishing a core story idea, but a 'quiet' mind is very helpful for coming up with original story ideas. The latter mode makes me think of the [Critical Brain Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_brain_hypothesis), where we seem to find the brain working a bit like a Cloud Chamber that uses an unstable amount of humidity to amplify the small signal of a particle that triggers condensation by it's path. We can do a lot by conceptualising, discussing, elaborating, comparing. But there also seems to be a mode of just quietly contemplating, that we often find really original thinkers and problem solvers are good at. Long walks, hot baths, ideas that arrive in dreams, and the 'still quiet voice' of intuition, seem to arise from a different way of using I minds, I think.

> look at a stone and visualize all the analogues that can be created
> from the stone

If you hear the story of [Michaelangelo's David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo)#Commission), the block was already part-carved, and considered very challenging in shape. It was the constraints, which made his vision all the more remarkable. Real creativity isn't imposed, it feels more like a discovery, something participatory between artist and medium.

It's interesting to consider the Japanese aesthetic [Wabi Sabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabi-sabi), and the tea-ceremony idea of [ichi-go-ichi-e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo)#Commission). These focus on the unrepeatable, irreplcable qualities, the uniqueness in objects, and in life. I think we would do well to take inspiration from this. In an age where we feel anyone with enough currency could buy a perfect copy of anything, we have forgotten the real meaning of 'treasure': unique objects, uncopyable heights of craftmanship from past ages, and unique stories and histories embodied in objects we treasure. Most things come off the 'production lines of our minds', but don't forget truly new unique things are still possible.

Comment: If communication with an octopus is possible, isn't it conceivable that the communication would be via analogy? Does a human'-octopus interaction require creativity?

Comment: @StevanV.Saban: I argue  base of common experience would be essential https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77261/according-to-the-major-theories-of-concepts-where-do-meanings-come-from/77284#77284 The examples of relatively successful inter-species communication are raising apes like humans & teaching them sign language, & captive corvids & pet dogs. That builds intersubjectivity. Is that a kind of analogy? I think that stretches the meaning of the word beyond breaking. It certainly seems when we look they look back: https://youtu.be/GdCOYToDqfM

Comment: I agree that I'm stretching and challenging the use and meaning analogy. I find it interesting that AI has not yet mastered this task. From a intelligence design perspective, I would consider analogy a core function.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban: Don't evolutionary algorithms use analogy? Don't AI art programs?

Comment: When I search online "can ai create analogies", I get a variety of answers. Some say no. The ones that say yes admit the current functionality is very limited. Since I'm not an expert, I want to make sure I really understand what is meant by the term "analogy".

Comment: If I were to design an artificial intelligence, one of the first functions I would develop is the ability to create and understand analogies. I would not consider it functionality to add on later as a feature.

Comment: "*what is meant by the term 'analogy'"* That is indeed the crux of this biscuit. You can't very well expect to programme a computer to do a task that can't be clearly articulated. Wittgenstein identified that for the word 'game' we feel we know 1 when we see it, but struggle to produce a strict exhaustive definition. He uses that to point at how language is not simply in words, but how we live, in the modes-of-life words are taught in. If 'analogy' is like 'game', can we expect anything less than a sentient AGI, that has made the jump from syntax to semantics, to be capable of it even..?